# Find the max number of occurrences of a substring in a string constructed by a list of strings

Tags: python

I want to find the max number of occurrences of a substring in a string constructed by a list of strings

For example:

- List: `["pyooo", "fhriaha", "ppyhap"]`
- Target string: "happy"

Solution: 2, by forming a string of `"fhriahappyhappyooo"`, there can be at most 2 occurrences of the word `"happy"`.

I tried to use `itertools.permutations` but it is not efficient, I want to find a more efficient way.

My code:

```
from itertools import permutations

max_cnt = 0
words = ["pyooo", "fhriaha", "ppyhapp"]
target = "happy"
for i in permutations(words):
    cnt = ''.join(i).count(target)
    max_cnt = max(max_cnt, cnt)
print(max_cnt)
```

Comment: Should the answer be 2, not 3?

Comment: Surely there are some words you can use to describe what you want to achieve. Also, in that string there are only 2 occurrences of "happy"? show the code of what you tried

Comment: "I tried to use itertools.permutations but it is not efficient" - how do you judge the efficiency of this approach with a sample input of only 3 strings?

Comment: Is your code really to slow in the real world? If yes... I'd always recommend to first profile your code and see where it spends its time. Premature optimization is the root of all evil, or so.

Comment: What if the target string is "dada", and the list is ["dadadadada", "dadadada"], should that count as 8 or as 4 or as 1 occurrence?

Comment: How efficient do you need it? How many strings do you have? How long are they? How long is the target?

Answer (score 1):

To make your code more efficient, replace the `for` loop with a list comprehension or generator expression and use the `max()` method on the result.

```py
from itertools import permutations

words = ["pyooo", "fhriaha", "ppyhap"]
target = "happy"

print(max("".join(_).count(target) for _ in permutations(words)))
```

**Profiled Code:**

```py
from itertools import permutations

def for_loop(words, target):
    max_cnt = 0
    for _ in permutations(words):
        cnt = "".join(_).count(target)
        max_cnt = max(max_cnt, cnt)
    return max_cnt


def gen_expr(words, target):
    return max("".join(_).count(target) for _ in permutations(words))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import cProfile

    words = ["pyooo", "fhriaha", "ppyhap"]
    target = "happy"
    functions = (for_loop,  gen_expr)


    for f in functions:
        print('=' * 25)
        print("Profiling:", f.__name__)
        print('=' * 25)
        pr = cProfile.Profile()
        for i in range(10**6):
            pr.runcall(f, words, target)

        pr.create_stats()
        pr.print_stats()
```

**Results:**

```
=========================
Profiling: for_loop
=========================
         20000000 function calls in 5.823 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1000000    3.258    0.000    5.763    0.000 test.py:3(for_loop)
  6000000    0.917    0.000    0.917    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
  6000000    0.939    0.000    0.939    0.000 {method 'count' of 'str' objects}
  1000000    0.060    0.000    0.060    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  6000000    0.650    0.000    0.650    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}

=========================
Profiling: gen_expr
=========================
         22000000 function calls in 5.789 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1000000    0.496    0.000    5.727    0.000 test.py:11(gen_expr)
  7000000    2.690    0.000    4.330    0.000 test.py:12(<genexpr>)
  1000000    0.901    0.000    5.231    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
  6000000    0.974    0.000    0.974    0.000 {method 'count' of 'str' objects}
  1000000    0.062    0.000    0.062    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  6000000    0.667    0.000    0.667    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
```

The results show that the generator expression wins.

Comment: Can you explain why this is more efficient? Isn't this just another way of writing the `for` loop, and doesn't the `max` function still have to look at each value? I'm assuming OP is looking for either performance (speed) or maybe optimizing memory use, but not to optimize for fewer bytes in his code.

Comment: The internal loop of a list comprehension runs at the CPython layer leading to a performance improvement (speed). For the given problem the gain in performance may seem negligible but in the real world it can be significant.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the profiler results.

Comment: @DanNagle Results will vary by platform. Python 3.12.1 on Silicon M2 gives 5.851 and 5.894 respectively. Hardly significant but using your argument it shows that gen_expr can be slower than for_loop

Comment: *"The internal loop of a list comprehension runs at the CPython layer"* - And their original loop doesn't? Why are you using a profiler instead of timeit? It seems to add a lot of overhead, and I'm not at all convinced that it doesn't affect the two solutions differently, so I don't trust your results to be meaningful.